# Is it possible to allocate items of boost::multi_index or boost::intrusive on vector?

Tags: c++, boost, multi-index

Is it possible to allocate items of boost::multi_index on vector and use indexes in this vector(4 bytes) instead of pointers(8 bytes) everywhere (including internal structures of boost::multi_index) to save memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *might* be possible: Boost.MultiIndex supports special allocators whose associated `Allocator::pointer` type can be something different than a regular pointer provided it models a random access iterator, as explained [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/multi_index_container.html#instantiation_types) (this is done primarly [to support Boost.Interprocess allocators](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/creation.html#special_allocator).) With some work you might craft an allocator that uses a vector as its arena and uses a 4-byte object to index it. Doesn't look like an easy task, though.